# Subview's size not equal to its superview

Tags: ios, swift

**Problem:**

The yellow part is the subview( **The subview is UIImageView, and the superview is UIView.** ), its size is suppose to be the same as its superview (the gray part), what should I do to fix this?

**Screen Images:**

[image]

**Here's the code:**

```
var linkedMemory = Memory(masteryLevel: 1, algorithm: Algorithm.algorithm1.chooseAlgorithm(), forgetRatio: 0, lastStudyTime: Date(), front: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Ideas-Yellow"), back: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Ideas-Blue"))

var frontView: UIView {
    let front = showContent(of: linkedMemory.front)
    return front
}

convenience init(memory: Memory) {
    self.init(frame: CGRect())
    self.linkedMemory = memory
    self.setupView()
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setupView()
}

func setupView() {
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    self.layer.shadowRadius = 12
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.15
    self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    addGesture()
    sizeNAddSubview(view: frontView)
}

func sizeNAddSubview(view: UIView) {
    view.frame.size = self.bounds.size
    addSubview(view)
}

func showContent(of linkenMemory: Any) -> UIView {
    var contentView = UIView()
    if let content = linkenMemory as? UIImage {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = content
        contentView = imageView
    }
    if let content = linkedMemory as? String {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        let text = content
        label.text = text
        contentView = label
    }
    return contentView
}
```

**Here are the constraints:**

[image]

Comment: pl. check `clipToBound` property of your subview and superview.

Comment: @RichardG for the superview it's false

Comment: are you using auto layout?

Comment: @RichardG yes, and clipToBounds is also off for the subview

Comment: what if your superview and subview (like UIImageView, UIView, etc.)? and if Its UIImageView then check its contentMode.

Comment: Can I see where you set your constraints? If you use constraints you don't need to set the frame.

Comment: @RichardG the subview is UIImageView and its contentMode is scale to fill

Comment: @JingJingTao plz see the edit

Comment: hmm, you don't need the aspect ratio, just set the edges of the subview the same as the super view. Also you don't have to add it to the superview if you have it in the storyboard. Is the flash card view the yellow view?

Comment: @JingJingTao oh the view on the storyboard is the superview, I added the subview programmatically.

Comment: Okay that makes more sense :D, could you print out the size of the views?

Comment: @JingJingTao I changed a few variable names and this problem just got magically solved, it seems to be caused by conflicting variable names

Comment: :p, okay cool, if you're bothered you could update your code and I can have a look why it is working, but if not no worries and all the best :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134750/discussion-between-bright-future-and-jingjingtao).

Comment: SET frame of your imageview to self.view.frame
if let image = linkedMemory as? UIImage { 
let imageView = UIImageView() 
imageView.image = image 
imageView.frame = self.view.frame
contentView = imageView 
}

Answer (score 1):

You can either give constraints as equal height and equal width of superview 
[or]
 If you are setting this view before layout pass, the size of superview will not be the actual size, so you've to move the code to either `viewDidAppear()` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`

Comment: What do you mean by "layout pass"?

Comment: @BrightFuture The process of determining size and position of views or subviews, and viewDidLayoutSubviews() will get triggered when this layout pass is completed.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Your flash card view is UIView.And you want to make it full screen, then follow this.